# Google Analytics: how to build a Goal which has several events

Tags: google-analytics, goals

I want to set up a Goal that consist in tracking 3 events: first, when the user clicks in a button. After this, when the user fills out into an input box, and finally another click in other button.

I guess I have to do it via a Goal, isn´t it? If I go  to Admin -> Goal -> New Goal, I can only put an only one event....

Anybody knows how to do it, please?

Regards,
Alejandro.

Comment: The goal is usually set as the last event.   So clicking that other button would be the "goal" and other steps could appear in the "goal funnel", except that GA doesn't support events for a goal funnel, only pages.

Comment: That is the question.....GA doesn´t support events for a goal funnel, therefore I won´t see anything displayed in the goal funnel......

Comment: [This forum](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Tracking-Goals/Events-based-Goal-set-up-and-Funnel-Visualization/td-p/940259) suggests using virtual pageviews rather than events so that they show up in the funnel.

Comment: In case I want to track 3 clicks in 3 different buttons and a final button named "Confirm". Can I do it with a goal? How can i set up the goal with all the events if GA only allows me one event? Thanks and regards, Alejandro